# Why does GeoServer's GetFeature round my numbers, but only for outputFormat=CSV?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, csv, floating-point, getfeature

When I make a GetFeature request with outputFormat=CSV  to my GeoServer v2.4.5 I'm finding that the floating point numbers in my returned data have been rounded. When I make the same request with other output formats the floats are returned correctly.

Here's the request returning XML:

```
 http://geothermal.smu.edu:9000/geoserver/gtda-contributions/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gtda-contributions:UNDRadiogenicHeat&maxFeatures=1&
```

This excerpt from the returned XML shows the data as it was entered into the backing database. There are more floating point numbers in the returned data, but I exclude them for brevity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gtda-contributions="http://scr.siemens.com/gtda-contributions" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scr.siemens.com/gtda-contributions http://geothermal.smu.edu:9000/geoserver/gtda-contributions/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=gtda-contributions%3AUNDRadiogenicHeat http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://geothermal.smu.edu:9000/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <gtda-contributions:UNDRadiogenicHeat fid="UNDRadiogenicHeat.2540ea6b-f94a-3088-9b32-762c77a8e57f">
            <gtda-contributions:latitude>47.90752513</gtda-contributions:latitude>
            <gtda-contributions:longitude>-92.79726665</gtda-contributions:longitude>
 ...
```

The same request with `outputFormat=application/json&`:

```
 http://geothermal.smu.edu:9000/geoserver/gtda-contributions/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gtda-contributions:UNDRadiogenicHeat&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application/json&
```

returns similar (correct) data:

```
 {
"type" : "FeatureCollection",
"totalFeatures" : 343,
"features" : [{
        "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : "UNDRadiogenicHeat.2540ea6b-f94a-3088-9b32-762c77a8e57f",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [-92.79726665, 47.90752513]
        },
        "geometry_name" : "shape",
        "properties" : {
            "latitude" : 47.90752513,
            "longitude" : -92.79726665,
...
```

However, if the request is for CSV:

```
 http://geothermal.smu.edu:9000/geoserver/gtda-contributions/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gtda-contributions:UNDRadiogenicHeat&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=csv&
```

the same portion of data has been rounded off (48 instead of 47.90752513, and -93 instead of -92.79726665):

```
 FID,latitude,longitude,...
 UNDRadiogenicHeat.2540ea6b-f94a-3088-9b32-762c77a8e57f,48,-93,...
```

I've looked for configurations that might cause this, but I see none.  I know there are filters that could do this, but I get the impression that these need to be explicitly requested, and the above requests do not include filters.

Is there something I'm overlooking? Is there some way that GeoServer is treating the data so glaringly differently just because I'm requesting CSV?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Have you asked the geoserver developers? Is the default decimal separator a ```,``` (rather than ```.```) in either the server or client locale?

Comment: The client locale on my test machine is en-us, as I expect is the case on my customer's machine (judging from the fact that in all other cases I've seen in the years I've worked with them I've not seen their machines display numbers with a different decimal separator, though I will confirm.) The server is en-us as well, so that should rule out locale differences. Also, other outputFormats work properly.

It might be a bug, but I didn't see anything on GeoServer's JIRA that fit any of my expected search terms. I'm writing to their users mailing list to explore further, and will report back.